# How to store an int in a char * that is assigned by malloc

Tags: c

I was trying to store an int value (all  4 bytes) into a *char **:

So, I would like to store the full value i.e all the bytes (all 4) of the int variable into the char such that I use up 4 bytes out of the 512 bytes. I should also be able to read back the value that I assigned. I tried to use a lot of the stuff but couldn't figure this out.

This is for my LFS (Log File System) where I try to store files into data blocks on my disk using fragmentation of data

```
char *c = malloc(512);
int value = 4096;
```

Comment: to allocate 512 bytes to only use 4 is expensive. Warning after the _memcpy_ the result depends if you are in big or little endian, and nothing says an _int_ is always on 4 bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy into the buffer pointed to by `c`:

```
memcpy(c, &value, sizeof(value));
```

If you want to write another value following that, you can add offset to `c`:

```
memcpy(c + sizeof(value), &value2, sizeof(value2));  // adds value2 at an offset right after value
```

To read the value, you can copy it into a different variable:

```
int readVal;
memcpy(&readVal, c, sizeof(readVal));
```

Comment: Thank You @ODYN-Kon. Was very helpful :)

Comment: No need for parenthesis here: `sizeof(value)` Using `sizeof value` would just do. `sizeof` is an operator not a function.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've written C or C++, but I believe you can use memcpy to do what you desire.

```
memcpy(c, &value, 4);
```

This should copy 4 bytes from the address of value into the bytes you allocated from c.  If you wanted to be sure about the size of the integer, you could use sizeof(int) instead of 4.  So that would be

```
memcpy(c, &value, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional pointers could be used.
Cast the char pointer to make it available to an int pointer. The int pointer can be used as an array and can be easily assigned or printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char *line = malloc ( 512);
    char *text = line + sizeof ( int) * 2;//reserve space for two int
    int *value = (int *)line;//cast to int pointer
    value[0] = 4096;//or *value = 4096;
    value[1] = 25;
    strcpy ( text, "text and more text");
    printf ( "%d\n", value[0]);//or printf ( "%d\n", *value);
    printf ( "%d\n", value[1]);
    printf ( "%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello @Xing, it is definitely useful to know how to add both int and text to a memory location and preserving their memory at the same time. I appreciate your effort! :)

Answer (score 1):

One could use a `union` to write directly to the value,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> /* C99 */

union Block {
    char c[512];
    int32_t d;
};

int main(void) {
    union Block *b;
    if(!(b = malloc(sizeof *b))) return perror("?"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    b->d = 4096;
    printf("%d\n", b->d);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I've used the C99 `int32_t` to ensure that it's 32 bits. However, the bit order (what is `b->c[0]`?) depends on if one is using little or big endian.